# mathematica and matlab interaction with NetLink and data exchange between them

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, netlink

I used  the following code in mathematica to call matlab

```
In[1]:= Needs["NETLink`"]
matlab = CreateCOMObject["matlab.application"]
In[5]:= matlab@Execute["a=[1 2;3 4]"]
```

I want to get matlab workspace variable "a" from mathematica and convert it to mathematica matrix.
How can i do this with netlink?

Comment: I do not have matlab, but assuming the output of `matlab@Execute["a"]` will be a string in Matlab format, you need to parse that string into valid Mathematica syntax. Alternatively, you can export vectors, matrices from matlab into a file, using a format that Mathematica can import.

Comment: @Sasha: How do you get the "ProgID" for any application?

Comment: @Jalil I recommend you to give some examples of the outputs you get when evaluating the code like `matlab@Execute["a=[1 2;3 4]"]`. Then it will be possible for someone to help you in writing a code for converting such output into *Mathematica*'s format.

Comment: @Alexey: if i write matlab@Execute["a=1;"] the i can not use ImportString command because of ";" .

Comment: @Jalil You should provide a set of example outputs which you wish to be able to convert into *Mathematica*'s format.

Comment: @Alexey How can i used `NETLINK` and `CreateComObject` in mathematica installed in ubuntu linux to call matlab?

Comment: @Jalil Native [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) exists only for Windows. For Linux you can try ports of .NET but I never tried it and know nothing on it. I think it is probably impossible to call COM objects under Linux since Linux has no COM.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how you connect with MATLAB... your `ProgID` doesn't work on mine, and I'm not sure if it is correct either. A simpler and more reliable way to do it would be to create whatever you want in MATLAB and then save it as a `.mat` file and import it into Mathematica. Here's a small example:

#### MATLAB:

```
a=magic(4)

a =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

save('file','a');
```

#### Mathematica:

```
a = Transpose@Import["file.mat", {"HDF5", "Datasets", "a"}];
```

[image]

Comment: is there any direct method to do this? Your answer has two stage.

Comment: @Jalil: As I mentioned, I couldn't get Mathematica to connect with MATLAB. If I could, I can perhaps try to figure out a way. Could you edit your question and explain why you use the `ProgID` "matlab.application"? How do you choose the correct ID for an arbitrary application? Also, I'm running a mac, so  I don't know if things are different. If you explain how to connect, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you get output of the form

```
out = "
  a =

      16     2     3    13
       5    11    10     8
       9     7     6    12
       4    14    15     1

  ";
```

you can convert this into *Mathematica*'s format by using `ImportString` command:

```
matrix = ImportString[out, "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
matrix // TableForm
```